# default paragraph font vs. underlying properties

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, fonts, styles

I am creating new character styles and I do not grasp what the difference is between based on either default paragraph font or underlying properties.

I'd appreciate any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference in resulting behavior from choosing "Default Paragraph Font" or "(underlying properties)".

Because built-in Character Styles are based on "Default Paragraph Font" and it is the default two user-created Character Styles, I suggest using this option.